# pagination first link disabled codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter pagination. The first link is disabled and the rest of the links are working. Even after going to the 2nd and 3rd link the first link remains disabled.

Controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/le0wallt1esadmin/specialoffer/viewsp/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('home');
$config['per_page'] =5;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;  
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Thanks,

Comment: do the pages show the right results or do they all show the first page?

Comment: the pages show the right result but the first link is disabled ie there is no link

Comment: maybe you can hardcode the current page with $config["cur_page"]. set this to 2 and tell me what happens? does the first link have a anchor after that?

Comment: to clarify, the current page shows no link at default. at page 4, are there 2 non-linked items in your pagination (1 and 4), or just 4?

Comment: that's the normal behaviour of the codeigniter pagination. the current page has no links.

Answer (score 1):

it is the current pagination behaviour of the codeigniter pagination library. to override this, you can specify

```
$config["cur_tag_open"] = "<a href='" + current_url() + "'>";
$config["cur_tag_close"] = "</a>";
```

and then you'll have the current page link.

Comment: my pagination is running locally but the same is not running on the server do u know why? any ideas please it is urgent

Comment: which link i can't give u the website link it is not allowed